# Merging several MySQL results into a single JSON encode (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here is code as exists now:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($count_query_result))
    $output[]=$row;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($average_query_result))
    $output2[]=$row;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($items_query_result))
    $output3[]=$row;

print(json_encode(array($output,$output2,$output3)));
mysql_close();
```

My question:

How do I take a single column from each of the three query results, and make a JSON array out of it, like so:

[{ 'att1' : 'data'}, { 'att2' : 'data'}, { 'att3' : 'data'}]

ASSUMING:

- att1 came from the $count_query_result/$output
- att2 came from the $average_query_result/$output2
- att3 came from the $items_query_result/$output3

Therefore, encoding only one variable, not 3.

Answer (score 1):

Well I answered my own issue.  I had to get to the very root of the problem.  The MySQL queries.  I have joined them  all so now there is just one.  This creates a single JSON array for what I need.  I believe there is something to be said about just doing it ... right .. the first time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array('att1' => $row['data'],
                'att2' => $row['data']

echo json_encode($result)
```

where $row['data'] is the information that you want returned from each of your queries

Comment: I'm not sure how this will work, though I thank you for your response (since no one else did).  The $row's are coming from three different query calls.  I don't think you can use them this way.

Comment: hey thanks.  I ended up answering my own question and just got to the root of the matter here.... (see above)