# Two MySQL output in single JSON encode in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have two MySQL output which I need to encode in a single JSON output.

Output 1:

```
$sql = "select * from t1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output[] = array_map("nl2br", $row);
    }
```

Output 2:

```
$sql2 = "select * from t2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output2[] = array_map("nl2br", $row2);
    }
```

This is what I am doing to get them in single JSON_encode:

```
echo json_encode($output.$output2);
```

still not getting both the outputs. I came to know of another solutions i.e. to merge both the queries but I am not able to do that as well. I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747098/merging-several-mysql-results-into-a-single-json-encode-php) also but no luck :(

Comment: `json_encode(array($output, $output2));`

Comment: @PaulBain Thanks for your help But this is giving the output as [[{"id":"1"}],[{"id":"2"}]] and I need the output as [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]

Comment: So just append your stuff to the first array. Instead of $output2[] = array_map("nl2br", $row2); do $output[] = array_map("nl2br", $row2); And finally do json_encode($output)

Comment: @Marius This didn't helped :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. How about using UNION in your query? Please check it out here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html
2. What about

   $fullOutput = array_merge($output1, $output2);
   echo json_encode($fullOutput);

Comment: $fullOutput = array_merge($output1, $output2); 
did it!! 
Thanks a lot!!